# AWS Elasticbeanstalk unit testing before deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was wondering if it was possible to play unit tests of an application before validating deployment when using Amazon Webservices and Elasticbeanstalk ?

I mean, if all the tests pass, then deployment is done, else an error is displayed.

Is that possible ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible with [commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands)

Comment: That was very vague for an answer